# what does a mail-transfer-agent.target do?

Tags: linux, opensuse

I tried searching everywhere on google and it won't provide any good information. What does the mail-transfer-agent.target specifically do? (I'm talking about the "TARGET" mail transfer agent)

Thanks in advance

Comment: mail-transfer-agent.target
The mail transfer agent (MTA) service. Usually this should pull-in all units necessary for sending/receiving mails on the local host.
 
systemd automatically adds dependencies of type After for this target unit to all SysV init script service units with an LSB header referring to the $mail-transfer-agent or $mail-transport-agent facilities, for compatibility with Debian. https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/systemd/systemd.special.7.en.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `.target` files as “meta-services”. Say you want to start a network daemon. It obviously requires the network to be up. There are many ways to configure the network (NetworkManager, systemd-networkd, ifupdown, …). You wouldn’t want to concern yourself with that, so instead you depend on `network-online.target`. The actual network configuration service is marked as a dependency of `network-online.target`.

In this case, the target means that a mail transfer agent (MTA) is available. Again, there are many different MTAs.

Package maintainers or software developers (the ones providing the default unit files) cannot know how your system is set up. By using this abstraction, the dependency tree is built correctly anyway.